# Raising a matrix's digits to the power of a sequence fast?

Tags: r, matrix, exponent

There is a matrix called A, which is an n x k matrix. It's digits are in complex forms. I'm trying to raise each row of matrix A to the rownum(th) exponent.

```
n <- 1000
k <- 10
x <- complex(real = runif(n*k), imaginary = runif(n*k))
A <- matrix(x, ncol = k, nrow = n)

Exponent_Matrix <- matrix(1:n, ncol = k, nrow = n)

Result <- A^Exponent_Matrix

library(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark(
  Result <- A^Exponent_Matrix,
  times = 1000
)
#0.000487secs
```

This is a solution that works, but it could it be done in a more efficient way? Also, the length of the matrix (n) can vary, but the colnum (k) is usually between 1 and 20.

Comment: you could get a small gain in not preallocating Exponent_Matrix and use A^(1:n) instead ... but we're in microseconds here

Comment: ... or you could see if transforming it gives a speed up ... e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1397437/formula-for-raising-a-complex-number-to-a-power